# primefaces:row edit event not working when click on pencil icon

Tags: java

i am using jsf,primefaces and hibernate i have fetch the data from database inside table when i am click in pencil icon it is not working and not any error or exception is generated and click it the compiler not going on our bean class i have get the name for one table and client name get from another database table it working only facility name column when define two column it not working

my xhtml page

```
               <p:dataTable id="allFacilityList" var="facility" rendered="true" value="#  {facilityBean.facilityList}" paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorPosition="top" styleClass="fixed-size" emptyMessage="No facility insdie faclity list" style="width:      965px;" editable="true">
           <p:ajax event="rowEdit" immediate="true" listener="#{facilityBean.onEdit}" update=":ftListForm"/>                          

<p:column headerText="Facility Name" style="width:60%; alignment-adjust: middle">
                         <p:cellEditor>
                             <f:facet name="output">
                                 <h:outputText style="alignment-adjust: middle" value="#{facility.name}" />
                              </f:facet>
                                  <f:facet name="input">
                                      <p:inputText value="#{facility.name}"  style="width:100%"/>
                                       </f:facet>
                                    </p:cellEditor>
                          </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="Client Name" style="width:60%; alignment-adjust: middle">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                             <f:facet name="output">
       <h:outputText style="alignment-adjust: middle" value="#{facility.clientName}" />
                                 </f:facet>
                                  <f:facet name="input">
              <p:inputText value="#{facility.clientName}"  style="width:100%"/>
                                       </f:facet>
                              </p:cellEditor>
                          </p:column>
```

my bean class row edit methode

```
     public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event)
     {
     System.out.println("onEdit methode of facility bean class");
    Facility facility=(Facility) event.getObject();
    facilityService.editFacilityList(facility);
       }
     myservice class editfacility method
    public void editFacilityList(Facility facility)
     {
           int userIdVal = (Integer) httpSession.getAttribute(Constants.USER_ID);
   facility.setUpdateUserId(userIdVal);    
    facility.setUpdateDate(new Date());
    facilityDao.attachDirty(facility);

 }
```

Comment: i have not get any exception or error when click the pencil icon pls help any one

Comment: please give me suggestion for this problem